# Component creation lead info not getting saved

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I was trying to create a project component from my plugin. Code is below,

```
com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent component =ComponentAccessor.getProjectComponentManager().create(“Sample Name”,“Sample description”,
“My Username”, AssigneeTypes.PROJECT_DEFAULT,“projectId”);
```

The component is getting created under the project specified but lead is not assigned. All other fields are reflected as expected.

My jira version is v7.10.1

When I create from project centric view, I am able to create the component with the required info.

Why the lead is not assigned to the component?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the project lead to the component you may try this:

```
ComponentAccessor.getProjectComponentManager().create("Sample Name","Sample description",
"My Username", AssigneeTypes.PROJECT_LEAD,"projectId");
```

Please note that not all project will have the default assignee as the project lead so assigning `AssigneeTypes.PROJECT_DEFAULT` may assign nobody to that component. You can check this in Project administration > Users and roles > Default assignee.

Comment: Thank you, Default assignee field is setting . But the lead info "My Username" is not getting set. Lead is showing as empty in my component page. But manage components page it is showing only the username. When I find using the lead, the component is not listing.